# PSQL. Migrating data from one DB to another DB with different table structure

Tags: sql, postgresql, migration, database-migration, psql

I have data on a PSQL-db that I need to migrate to another PSQL-db. The biggest problem is that the structure of the DB's is different.

So my question is what is the smartest way of doing this kind of migration?

My initial thoughts was to map where all the data should go in the new DB in a excel sheet and then write some kind of script that inserts the old data into the new DB.

This seems a little tedious and i'm wondering if anyone know any tool or methods to make this easier/faster?

Comment: import existing table into new db and leave old as it is.

Comment: I can't just import it because the new DB has a different table structure. The new DB also already have data in it.

Comment: So are you looking to create new table in DB2 to insert data from DB1?

Comment: is the data different in two db's tables

Comment: @wingᴇd pᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ Not quite. I already have the tables setup on my DB2. Now I just need to get the data from DB1 in DB2 but the table structure is different in DB1 vs DB2 but the data is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new table with an extra field that show

> imported

Get data from another db and then create a view of both tables.

This may also help you

[Data Import Tip](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Oracle/Q_21750170.html)